# php variable to include

Tags: php, include

I am wondering what is the best option to use variables in an included file who are declared in his parent file.

When I want to check privileges in an included file because I do not want to copy the whole function to any file I want to check the privileges.

I tried a few ways. Which is the best, or should I do it another way?

just include:

```
<?php
// head file
$userlevel = 2;
$minimumlevel
include('testprivileges.php');
?>

<?php
// testprivileges file
if ($userlevel < $minimumlevel){
  die('no privileges');
}
```

or

```
<?php
//head file
$userlevel;
$minimumlevel
include('checkprivileges.php?userlevel=$userlevel&minimumlevel=$minimumlevel');
// i dont care this wont work. you understand what I try to do
?>

<?php
$userlevel = $_GET['userlevel'];
// and check for privileges
?>
```

or

```
<?php
// testprivileges function file
function testprivileges($userlevel, $minimumlevel){
  if($userlevel < $minimumlevel){
    die('no privileges');
  }
}
?>

<?php
//head file
$userlevel = 2;
$minimumlevel = 3;
include('testprivilegesfile.php');
testpriviles($userlevel, $minimumlevel);
?>
```

or are all of those options bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code works, and its the best practice.

Your second example is bad because this:

```
include('checkprivileges.php?userlevel=$userlevel&minimumlevel=$minimumlevel');
```

cant work.

Your last code is also a bad practice because you have to copy paste the same function to every file. Not only is that duplication of code, but also hard to manage.

Like I said, the first code works best.

Some notes though:

**$userlevel** Should come from high above. You shouldn't have to re-declare it in every file. Just set it once in a global config.php.

**$minimumlevel** = minimum level for current page?

Ideal code:

```
<?php
    $minimumlevel = 1;
    require_once ('includes/config.php'); // Contains $userlevel

    Checkrights($minimumlevel);

?>
```

**functions.php**

```
function Checkrights($minimumlevel){
    global $userlevel;
    if ($userlevel < $minimumlevel){
      die('no privileges');
    }
}
```

**config.php**

```
  require_once ('functions.php');
  $userlevel = 2;
```

---

## Bitwise permission system

If you are really into a better permission system you might want to hit this tutorial about the bitwise permission system. I use it myself and its VERY simply. If you create a new table in SQL containing some permissions, you can give privileges PER module per sé. Highly recommended.

http://www.php4every1.com/tutorials/create-permissions-using-bitwise-operators-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

Simply just include in the beginning of the file if you will use it.

```
<?php
include("testprivileges.php");

//use to check privilege
?>
```

Comment: you mean: third option?